# When does the ListView items have been drawn to the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to know when the `ListView` layout is created. I need to perform an action on the item views, for that I need to know when the layout has been drawn to the screen. I need to get the IDs of the created views.

Is there a way to know when this is done ?

Edit (precision):

- Calling right after the `ListView,notifyDataSetChanged` doesnt work, `ListView.getChildCount` still returns `0`.
- I display a limited number of items, all items are displayed on the screen.

Comment: I think the each item is created when the adapter is setting.

Comment: read this tutorials you will get all details in there. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: https://youtu.be/wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: I think I know pretty well how the `ListView` works. I tried to do it after the `notifyDataSetChanged` but the GridView's child count is still at 0. I will take a look at those tutorials nonetheless

Comment: each child view is inflated in getView method in adapter

Comment: @Nithinlal so you think the only way should to *listen* in the getView and remember which views are created ? I need to know when ALL of them have been created

Comment: pls check u r update the data before calling notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: @ThomasRoulin *All* of them won't be created at the same time (excepted the case where you have a small number of items and almost all of them are displayed on the screen at the same time). A `ListView` is re-using subviews: if 10 items are visible at a time, only a dozen or so subviews will be created.

Comment: @MarcPlano-Lesay You are right, I should have precised that, actually I display a limited number of item. They are all on the screen.

Comment: for more information in listview pls check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: use listView.post(runnable) after setadapter is called on it. in the run method of the runnable you find the listview is drawn on the screen

Comment: As discussed above "getView method in adapter", you may save in array across the position of each row view.

Comment: May I ask you if you need to know all the IDs or when ListView finished drawing ALL the items?

Comment: @Sid I need to know all the view ids. Because my final objective is to define the nextfocus view id of each view.

Comment: @ThomasRoulin And you also sure that all views are displayed at the same time? Because that can change a lot of things

Comment: @Sid Yep, Each item is fully displayed on the screen. Always.

Comment: @ThomasRoulin I'll make some test and will get back to you :)

Comment: @Sid Thanks dude. I'm making tests on my side too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128934/discussion-between-sid-and-thomas-roulin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to gett all the IDs from the view I've tried the following

```
private List<View> mChildren;
```

I've declared a `List` of `View` which will contain all the children and then I managed to get all the children with the following snippet

```
ViewTreeObserver obs = mListView.getViewTreeObserver();
obs.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        for(int index = 0; index<((ViewGroup)mListView).getChildCount(); ++index) {
            View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)mListView).getChildAt(index);
            if(!mChildren.contains(nextChild)){
                mChildren.add(nextChild); //New Child to add
            }

        }
    }
});
```

And then you can you `mChildren` which contain all the children views. Otherwhise you can also check **[onFinishInflate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onFinishInflate())**. Hope it helps :)

### Update

As me and Thomas were discussing in chat, I came back to memory that also `onViewAdded` (from API 23) can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The adapter needs to create a layout for each row of the list. The `ListView` instance calls the `getView()` method on the adapter for each data element. In this method the adapter creates the row layout and maps the data to the views in the layout.

Within the `getView()` method you would inflate an XML based layout and then set the content of the individual views based on the Java object for this row. To inflate the XML layout file, you can use the `LayoutInflator` system service.

Below is the example adapter for `Listveiw`.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] values;

        public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
                super(context, -1, values);
                this.context = context;
                this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
                TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                textView.setText(values[position]);
                // change the icon for Windows and iPhone
                String s = values[position];
                if (s.startsWith("iPhone")) {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
                } else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
                }

                return rowView;
        }
}
```

Below is `rawlayout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="22px"
        android:layout_height="22px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, right ? I know how to make a `ListView`

Comment: Please update your question accordingly, your question say that "I want to know when the ListView layout is created. I need to know when the layout has been drawn to the screen". Please be specific with your question. So. we can help you to find right solution.

Comment: Not the answer but still +1 for the efforts :)